# How to update a Google Cloud Group instance

Tags: load-balancing, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've started to use Google Cloud Platform and I got some troubles understanding how it works.

Here's what I've done so far :

- I've created an Google Compute Instance using Wordpress Click-to-deploy image
- I've made a snapshot of this instance
- I've made an image from this snapshot
- I've made an instance **template** with this image
- I've made a instance **group** based on this template
- I've created a load-balancer using this instance group

Everything's working fine :  I can access my website.

For what I've understood so far is that each instance created by the group is "independant" : I've put differents PHP scripts inside each instance (like 'echo "1" ' in instance 1 and 'echo "2" ' in instance 2) and "each" time I refresh the page, it displays '1' or '2'

Here's my problem : If I want to add a post or to update the WP (like adding a plugin or editing the CSS), in which instance should I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new instance template and [roll it out to the instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups). Tune the updater with your instance replace preferences.

Updating static content like CSS may be a different process. Upload uniquely named files to CDN or other static file web server. Reduces the number of instance deploys, and allows uploads straight to a storage bucket or similar.

Comment: We've finally decided that we won't use the load balancer for this site but I'll give a try this updater thing ! I'll mark this as the right answer as the provided link seems to be what I needed for my case